# How to best handle Stripe API keys on the server

Tags: security, server, stripe-payments

I wonder how to correctly handle Stripe API keys on the server. I am using Stripes metered billing feature and the server is billing my clients automatically. Therefore, I'm quite concerned about the security of the API calls.
I recently found out, that I can set up restricted APi keys in Stripe. (A feature that I feel is not stressed enough in Stripe API tutorials.) But now I'm wondering how to best handle Stripe keys on the server. Do you store it encrypted (any real benefit if the server gets hacked)? Do you store it plain-text (in some config file)? Do you store it at all? I think about manually copy-pasting it into the server app, so it is actually stored in server application memory only - would you think this will be a true security improvement in case something gets corrupted?

In respect to security there seems to be many questionable Stripe API tutorial out there - so I think it would be nice to have some discussion about production level approaches here.

Comment: API keys in general should be stored encrypted .. plain text is no no... but generally configuration values are stored in solutions like Vaults of other Key Management System..

Comment: Ok, if I store the API keys encrypted, how do I store the encryption key? Wouldn't encryption just shift the key problem to the encrption system?

Comment: Is it going to be an On Prem or a Pure Cloud deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

Use best practices for secret management suitable for your environment and approved by your organization. This might be an "environment variable" or something provided with the startup command.

https://stripe.com/docs/keys#safe-keys

Restricted keys are a good approach if your integration is split across a number of focused microservices that don't need broad API access.

https://stripe.com/docs/keys#limit-access

Comment: Thank you for the links provided, however I do not see any valuable information in there concerning my question. My question basically is what to do with the key - how to handle it correctly (not negligent). And from a practical perspective - how do people actually store it? And how should it be stored?

Comment: That's because it depends on your server env. Some will use a private file on the server, possibly encrypted and decrypted at run time. Some will use the env var config on Netlify or Vercel or Glitch. Some will use AWS/Google Cloud key management systems. There's no universal answer beyond, like Gandalf says to, "keep it secret, keep it safe".